# How to change "Who can view the membership of the group" Group Members to Everyone through csom javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model, groups

I was wondering if it's possible to alter a setting of a group such as `Who can view the membership of the group`?

Setting from Group Members to Everyone through CSOM or through SP's web services.

Right now I am creating a group using the AddGroup web service, but I can't seem to find any documentation on altering this setting. Any ideas?

for group creation I have followed below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var siteUrl = '';
    function createListItem() {
    var getvalue = document.getElementById('<%=txtcategory.ClientID%>').value;
    var membersGRP = new SP.GroupCreationInformation();
    membersGRP.set_title(getvalue + '_Support_Group');
    membersGRP.set_description('desc');(membersGRP);
    oMembersGRP = currentWEB.get_siteGroups().add(membersGRP);
    clientContext.load(oMembersGRP);
    oMembersGRP = currentWEB.get_siteGroups().add   
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
</script>
```

Comment: It seems that part of your code is missing.

Comment: @Chakri : Your code looks incomplete. Also the way you have explained your question is not clear. I suggest you to rephrase it, in order to get more attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change membership visibility via CSOM using `set_onlyAllowMembersViewMembership` function:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
var web = context.get_web()
var groups = web.get_siteGroups()
var info = new SP.GroupCreationInformation()
info.set_title('new_group')
var group = groups.add(info)
group.set_onlyAllowMembersViewMembership(false) //this line sets membership visibility
group.update()
context.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, errorHandler)
```

Comment: Thank u dstarkowski,its working fine